# How can I show all registered users per event in Calendar?

Tags: users, entities, datetime

I am using Entity Registration together with Calendar. I'm trying to list all registered users in the event, but I don't know how to configure the view properly. Take a look at this image:
 [image]

I only want one listing of the event and then all the registrants inside that entry. Now it lists one event per registrant.

The view is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by creating a seperate view for registrants and then with the module Views field View I could show that view inside the Calendar view

Comment: Who is "I"??? looking at the userid who posted this answer, it has a different user id and a different profile image as compared to the user who posted the question ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens the first user (who posted the question) is unregistered, which means he did not register the account, and possibly lost the cookie he got when posting it. Most likely the author of the answer is the same person, this time creating a full account. No way for us to prove, and best course of action is to flag the answer and ask a moderator to contact a CM that will merge the accounts, if they're really the same person.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens no Drupal for me, just dropped by while checking your profile here. :) (first checked you are not suspended, then went over your activity to see if anything is going on, and noticed that comment, where my SE experience might come useful. :))